# JPA - updating objects in OneToMany-Relations

Tags: java, jpa

Well I am a little confused because I just can't find any solution on my problem (maybe some kind of a blackout)

Lets say I have the following (simplified) Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    private Collection<Phone> phones;
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee owner;
}
```

and I have a **phone** object managed by JPA. And now i want to change the Employee of that **phone** object with something like that:

```
phone.setEmployee(otherEmployee);
```

I thought that JPA would update the corresponding Employee would be updated too. Am I wrong?
I experimented with the annotations @ManyToOne and @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) but it doesn't work.

Do I have to update the Employee object myself? Unfortunatly I didn't find that case in any tutorial or other example, so I hope you can tell me more, I am confused. Thanks in advance.

**Edit** to make it even clearer:

```
Phone phone = new Phone();
Employee employee = new Employee();
phone.setEmployee(employee);
em.persist(employee);
em.persist(phone);

employee.getPhones(); //the phone object should be included here.
```

Comment: Since you're not removing, `CascadeType.REMOVE` won't do you any good. Try with `CascadeType.PERSIST` instead or `CascadeType.ALL`.
Also, I take it, that you're saving the `phone` object after you've changed the `Employee` relation, right?

Comment: Thats right, I had CascadeType.ALL but unfortunatly that is not the solution (I edited it for clarity now).

the **phone** with its owner was saved in the DB and was read by `em.find(...)`. And now I want to change the owner. (And of course the corresponding Employee-object should be updated too)

Comment: So after changing the owner to the other `Employee` object, did you call em.merge(phone);?

Comment: I edited the question again. Formating in comments is complicated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters) is the answer to your question, you should manage relationships by yourself, i. e.:

```
class Phone {
...
   void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
      owner = employee;
      employee.addPhone(phone);
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I thougth it would be managed by JPA itself.
Thanks!